# GWT - Avoid to listen to events

Tags: gwt, widget, keyboard-events

I'm using SliderBar widget from Google Web Toolkit Incubator. By default, this widget listens to some keyboard events, e.g. left arrow. I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid the widget listens to those events.

I'm using UiBinder and tried to use the function unsinkEvents but nothing happens. Here's the snippet of code:

@UiField(provided = true)
    SliderBar slbRotate;

```
public NewViewImpl() {
    slbRotate = new SliderBar(-180,180);
    slbRotate.setStepSize(10);
    slbRotate.setCurrentValue(0);       
    slbRotate.setWidth("478px");
    slbRotate.setHeight("22px");            
    slbRotate.unsinkEvents(Event.KEYEVENTS);
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));

}
```

I also used KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT in the argument of the unsinkEvents function, but doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the

```
unsinkEvents
```

function.

I created  a short example to show the basics:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;

public class ExtendedTextBox extends TextBox {
    public ExtendedTextBox() {
        sinkEvents(Event.KEYEVENTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        Window.alert("keypress");
    }

    public void unSinkKeyEvent(){
        unsinkEvents(Event.KEYEVENTS);
    }
}
```

This example creates a TextBox and whenever you press a key two MessageBoxes (one for the keydown one for the keyup) pop up. If you call the unSinkKeyEvent function this behafios stops.

So if you don't want to have speciffic behavior on SliderBar widget you just have too call the unsinkEvents function an specify the event you don't want to have (just look at the help)

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: I tried to use that function in UiBinder but didn't work. Is there a different way to do that in UiBinder.

Comment: I suppose you are using Eclipse. Just open your *ui.xml, go into the design mode (on the bottom left side) select the element you want to add events to, select "show events" double click on the event you want to create and define what it should do :). Pretty great isn't it how easy that works ;)

Comment: I'm using an HTMLPanel to wrap the widgets. I added the event onPanelAttachOrDetach and called the unsinkEvents functions, it works now. Thanks.